# Rigging scissor-mechanism

Tags: rigging, armature

Good afternoon,

I recently ran into this issue where I want to rig a scissor-like construction. I have tried different rigging constructions based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d0e1JBr9ng), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTjwe_mryI0) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9hPPeJrUmA) video. Although none of these tutorials seems to do the job.

Below I added an image of the scissor-construction. The green points are joints, the red point is a fixed point, and the green arrows indicate the limited freedom of movement of that joint.

What would an armature for such a construction look like? And which constraints would apply?

[image: Red point is fixed. Green points are joints. Green arrow indicate limited freedom.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

From bone A extrude B and C, unparent C and set an IK constraint on B, targeting at C.

Add D, child of B (keep offset)

Add E, child of A, and extrude H from E.

From D extrude F and G, and add an IK constraint on G, targeting at H, chain lenght 2.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfect!